# Always need to make static

Tags: java, class, object, netbeans, static

I am working on a project, and I have come across something i do not fully understand yet.

Every time I like to call a method from another class, or use a variable from a jform my netbeans says that I need to make it "static". Now I understand what static means, and I have created objects from the class that I use methods from, but even then netbeans says that I need to make the object static before i can use it in the MAIN() method. Even the jform variables like comboboxes.

can somebody please explain this?

thanks in advance!

EDIT:

this is some code from my project. It's very small but it should clarify the problem:

the Mainclass:

```
    public class SpeeloTheek {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static Controller MainController = new Controller();
public static SummaryScreen MainSummaryScreen = new SummaryScreen();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    MainSummaryScreen.setVisible(true);
    MainController.SetFullScreen(MainSummaryScreen);

    MainController.ComboBoxItemSelected(SummaryScreen.choiceBox);
}
```

the controller class:

```
    package speelotheek;

    import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
    import javax.swing.JComboBox;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Controller {

//Method to make JFrame fullscreen//
public void SetFullScreen(JFrame frameToUse) {
    frameToUse.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
}

public void ComboBoxItemSelected(final JComboBox comboBoxToUse) {

    comboBoxToUse.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                WhichSummary(comboBoxToUse);
            }
        }
    });

}

public void WhichSummary(JComboBox comboBoxToUse) {

    System.out.println(comboBoxToUse.getSelectedItem());

}

}
```

EDIT2:

Thanks all :) I found the problem. I instantiated the class in the main method instead above the main method and it worked :)

Comment: Are you doing it from the main method of the class? Trying to call a function which is non-static from your main method?

Comment: Work from the constructor instead of the `main`

Comment: Please post some code where the error occurs, and the complete error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you are working within the main method, which is static

```
public static void main(String[] args){

}
```

you can only call static elements, such classes, enum or static methods.

If you want to call a method member of a class from your main method, you have two options

**Make the method static**

```
class ClassA{
    public static void methodOne(){
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
     ClassA.methodOne();
}
```

**Instantiate the class in your main and call the non-static method.**

```
class ClassA{
    public void methodOne(){
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
     ClassA classA = new ClassA();
     classA.methodOne();
}
```

**Advice**
You have to take care while using static methods, because they share its memory.

when you create a new class `ClassA classA = new ClassA();`, for each new class you create, it stores its own non-shared memory variables, but when you use static methods, they share the memory which could be dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

In order to call non-static members of a class you need to instantiate an object.

Example:

```
Foo myObject = new Foo();  // myObject is an object of class Foo

Foo.callToStaticMember();  // static members can be called using the class name

myObject.callToNonStaticMember(); // non-static members require an object of the class
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because your main method is a static method.

From a static method you can't call the non static method's or variablen.
You need to change your main method to a constructor.
Then this code will be executed when you make an new instance of this class.

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to access non-static methods from the main method. It would not work. The reason being, that static methods/variables do not belong to the instance of the class.

If you do need to access a non static method in your main method of another class. the only way to do it is through the instance of the class.

So, you would need to say

```
MyClass object = new MyClass();
object.aMethod();
```

**EDIT**

Do you want your application to be all static? Basically, static would mean that it will have only one memory location. So, for eg: if a user selects a radio button on one screen. it modifies the value in your code, and another user selects another radio button, it will overwrite the previous user's value.

What you do need to do is something like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
Application appObject = new Application();
appObject.setController(new Controller());
appObject.setSummaryScreen(new SummaryScreen()); // Or pass these values through a constructor. Setters are just one way to do it. Or better yet, use Spring DI. 
appObject.performAction();

}

public Class Application {


public Controller MainController ;
public SummaryScreen MainSummaryScreen ;

.... getters and setters of these instance variables. 

public performAction(){
  MainSummaryScreen.setVisible(true);
    MainController.SetFullScreen(MainSummaryScreen);

    MainController.ComboBoxItemSelected(SummaryScreen.choiceBox);
}

}
```

Comment: and as a convention, generally do not use the objectnames starting with a capital letter

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Netbeans GUI Builder, what you want to do is work from the constructor, instead of the `main` method

```
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponent();

    jComboBox1.addItem("Hello");

    // do everything with your components here
}
```

All the objects declared by the GUI Builder are non-static. They're not meant to be accessed from the `main`.